# JPA Model with Optional table

Tags: java, jpa

Why cannot we have a **JPA** Model with optional existence of **table** in Relational DB?

Something like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY", optional = "true")
public class Category {
```

My use case is a multi-tenancy application with some tenant specific features.

Comment: Because JPA wasn't designed to support entities that may or may not be available.

Comment: What's the point of it? Could you describe a specific case where a table can be optional indeed? Plus how does it look like from DB point of view? For example, how do you expect it to be if there is a foreign key to this table? Optionality for a foreign key too? Which means optionality for all constraints too? It will end up with optionality for the whole database :)

Comment: My use case is a multi-tenancy application with some tenant-specific features